# Usage of Array of abstract types in Julia

Tags: arrays, julia, strong-typing

I'm exploring Julia so I'm a newbie. Now I'm exploring its strongly typed features. What I'm realizing is that I can't see the usage of abstract types for arrays. Let me explain with an example:

Let's suppose that I would like to create a function which accepts arrays of reals, no matter its concrete type. I would use:

```
function f(x::Array{Real})
  # do something
end
```

This function can be never called without raising a `f has no method matching f(::Array{Float64,1})`

I would like to call `f([1,2,3])` or `f([1.,2.,3.])` as long as the type of the element is Real.

I've read that you could promote or convert the array (p.eg `f(convert(Array{Real}, [1, 2, 3]))` or so) but I see that way really non-dynamic and tedious.

Is there any other alternative rather than getting rid of the strongly typed behaviour?

Thanks.

Comment: You can define a parametric function: `function f{T<:Real}(x::Array{T})`. This would capture both `f([1,2,3])` and `f([1.,2.,3.])`.

Comment: Just adding to @user3580870 comment: there is no performance penalty associated with parametric functions. It is an absolutely integral feature of Julia.

Comment: Yes, thanks for your comment, you are right. I was about to add this alternative as a "tedious alternative" as well but I finally regretted it. This solution doesn't satisfy me either because it can't be used for anonymous functions.

Comment: If speed is not an issue, you can define `f(x::Array)` and check `@assert eltype(x)<:Real`, first thing in the function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To expand upon the solution by [@user3580870](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3580870/user3580870), you can also use a `typealias` to make the function definition a little more succinct:

```
typealias RealArray{T<:Real} Array{T}
f(x::RealArray) = "do something with $x"
```

And then you can use the typealias in anonymous functions, too:

```
g = (x::RealArray) -> "something else with $x"
```

Comment: Definitely for me it's the best solution. Thanks :)

Answer (score 4):

Since there's been an updated since the orginal answer, the keyword `typealias` is gone so that the solution of [@Matt B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/176071/matt-b) would now be

```
const RealArray{T<:Real} = Array{T}
f(x::RealArray) = "do something with $x"
```

I'll just put this here for the sake of completeness ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this explicitly using the `<:` [subtype operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/base/#Core.:%3C:):

```
function f(x::Array)
    return zero.(x)
end

function f(x::Array{<:Real})
    return one.(x)
end

@show f([1, 2])
@show f([1.0, 2.0])
@show f([1im, 2im])
```

prints

```
f([1, 2]) = [1, 1]
f([1.0, 2.0]) = [1.0, 1.0]
f([1im, 2im]) = Complex{Int64}[0+0im, 0+0im]
```

Comment: Add some explanation on your answer.